# woocommerce - display variations in stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have enabled the attributes widgets on the shop page. 
My products use two attributes: style and size. Let's say a customer selects style as boys and size as large. All the products with the variation boys large show up.

But many of these variations are out of stock. How can I restrict the display to show only products with that variation that is in stock?

example: display products with the variation (boys large) in stock and hide products with the variation (boys large) out of stock.

Answer (score -1):

From the dashboard:

- Go to the WooCommerce -> Settings
- In the settings go to the Products tab and then Inventory sub-tab
- About 3/4 way down the page there is an option called "Out Of Stock Visibility", tick it
- Save the changes and the if the variation is out of stock it should no longer appear as an option.

[image]

Comment: thanks @Howlin for your answer.
but perhaps i didnt explain the problem correctly.

i know that this option will hide the particular variation from the product page. but my problem is, on the shop page, if someone selects those two filters from widgets on the sidebar all products show up irrespective of variation stock.

even if i enable the *hide out of stock.. option* the product will still show up on the shop page with the selected fiters.

Comment: Downvote because this doesn't answer how to query variations in code.